# asp.net Dynamic Chart data-bind post-back error

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, dynamic, data-binding, charts

I am dynamically data-binding a chart with multiple series.

```
<asp:Chart ID="Chart1" runat="server" EnableViewState="true">
    <ChartAreas>
        <asp:ChartArea Name="ChartArea1">
        </asp:ChartArea>
    </ChartAreas>
</asp:Chart>
```

This is the page code, please note Enable View-State is set to be true (i have also tried this without the view-state being enabled)

```
Public Sub PlotChart(Chart As Chart, Datasource As Object, ChartTitle As String, X_Axis As String, Y_Axis As String, Chart_Width As Integer, Chart_Height As Integer)

    If Not Page.IsPostBack Then
        Chart.Titles.Add(ChartTitle)
        Chart.ChartAreas(0).AxisX.Interval = 1
        Chart.ChartAreas(0).AxisX.TextOrientation = DataVisualization.Charting.TextOrientation.Rotated90
        Chart.Legends.Add("Legend")
        Chart.ChartAreas(0).AxisX.Title = X_Axis
        Chart.ChartAreas(0).AxisX.TextOrientation = DataVisualization.Charting.TextOrientation.Horizontal
        Chart.ChartAreas(0).AxisY.Title = Y_Axis
        Chart.Width = Chart_Width
        Chart.Height = Chart_Height
    End If

    Chart.DataSource = Datasource


    Dim NewCheckBoxList As New CheckBoxList
    Dim NewControl As New HtmlGenericControl("div")
    Form.Controls.Add(NewControl)

    Chart.Series.Clear()

    For x = 0 To Datasource.Columns.Count - 2

        Dim ChildControl As New HtmlGenericControl("div")

        Dim NewCheckBox As New CheckBox
        NewCheckBox.Text = Datasource.Columns(x + 1).Caption
        NewCheckBox.ID = "chk" & Chart.ID & Datasource.Columns(x + 1).Caption
        If Not Page.IsPostBack Then
            NewCheckBox.Checked = True
        End If

        If x = 0 Or x = 2 Then
            NewCheckBox.Checked = False
        End If

        ChildControl.Controls.Add(NewCheckBox)
        NewControl.Controls.Add(ChildControl)


        Chart.Series.Add(Datasource.Columns(x + 1).Caption)
        Chart.Series(x).XValueMember = Datasource.Columns(0).Caption
        Chart.Series(x).YValueMembers = Datasource.Columns(x + 1).Caption
        Chart.Series(x).ChartType = DataVisualization.Charting.SeriesChartType.Line

        Dim findCheckbox As CheckBox = FindControl("ctl00$chk" & Chart.ID & Datasource.Columns(x + 1).Caption)
        If Not findCheckbox.Checked Then
            Chart.Series(x).Enabled = False
        End If
    Next x

    Chart.DataBind()

End Sub
```

This is the procedure I'm using to bind the chart, this is run on every postback like so.

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load ' runs when the page is loaded

    Dim NSPAMonthlyFiguresTable_Adapter As New NSPATableAdapters.blaSp_GetNSPAMonthlyFiguresTableAdapter
    Dim NSPAMonthlyFigures_Adapter As NSPA.blaSp_GetNSPAMonthlyFiguresDataTable = NSPAMonthlyFiguresTable_Adapter.GetData()
    PlotChart(Chart1, NSPAMonthlyFigures_Adapter, "NSPA Monthly Figures", "Month", "Count Of PO's", 1024, 768)
End Sub
```

Question: When i run this it works fine, it draws the graph and has something like 8 series on it. HOWEVER if i tell it to draw the graph after a postback the graph won't display.

Regular chart https://i.stack.imgur.com/xcGQK.png

Post-back chart https://i.stack.imgur.com/gu1Q9.png

as you can see the second chart does display the chart title and it's doing something else because you can see the displacement of the check boxes at the bottom of the screen, it's just not giving me an error message or anything i can track to solve this issue.

I have been stuck on this for a few days, I left it for a few days then came back to it and still i can't figure this out. I have done multiple searches on google and in stack and i can't find anything that helps.

In essence I'm trying to bind a chart dynamically and replace the legend with a set of check boxes that can turn on and off visibility of series so other developers can bind a graph and have this functionality by only passing in the data source without having to have a ton of controls on the screen to manipulate the SQL.

thanks for your time and patience

Dave H